# Ограничения в 500 запросов с одного IP

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Нам для загрузки остатков из моисклад в интернет-магазин нужно выполнять подряд около 320 запросов с промежутком в 0,5 секунды (со временем количество запросов будет увеличиваться). Но у в документации по API мойсклад есть ограничение в 500 запросов с одного IP (Не более 500 запросов с одного ip-адреса). Хотелось бы уточнить: в какой промежуток времени это ограничение действует? В документации очень непонятно это описано и не хотелось бы получить ограничение на рабочем аккаунте (на тестовом все работает, но там нет такого количества товаров).

Comment: «Но у Вас» — у нас это у кого? Stack Overflow не является сайтом техподдержки МойСклад.

Comment: У мойсклада, конечно-же. Техподдержка МойСклад сказала, что этот вопрос надо задавать тут, а не им. Мол, их разработчики ответят тут. Почему-то так.

Comment: Тут действительно есть разработчики МойСклад и они иногда отвечают, но в целом Stack Overflow не имеет к нему отношения, так что «у Вас» смотрится странно. Впрочем, желание техподдержки свалить всё на сторонний сайт тоже выглядит странно

Comment: Поправил вопрос, раз эта часть вопроса больше всего вызывает непонимание ))). Меня тоже это удивило, что они вместо того, чтобы объяснить суть их же ограничений, отправили меня сюда )))

Comment: @andreymal наверняка не хотят посылать клиента по официальному каналу :)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что на него могут дать ответ только представители МойСклад

Answer (score 0):

500 запросов - это баг доки. Мы избавились от лимитов по IP.